# string to char conversion in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, string

I am getting `extLogonName` string for database, and depend upon the last char (number or alphabet) i need to change my logic. 
 i am using length -1 to get last char

```
char last = extLogonName[extLogonName.Length-1];
```

extLogonName is "moni.yewriwe2", but somehow last is returning me 50'2', i am only expecting 2.But now sure from where 50 is coming ?

After that i try to convert  `char last = System.Convert.ToChar(last1);`
it still showing me 50'2'.Actually i want to create login name, if same login name add number after it  Please find my complete logic.

```
  if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        extLogonName = (string)reader["logonname"];
                    }

                }
                   // char last = extLogonName[extLogonName.Length-1];
               // String NewString = Substring(oldString.Length - 1, 1); 
                //String last = Substring(extLogonName.Length - 1, 1); 
              string last1=  extLogonName.Substring(extLogonName.Length-1,1);

              char last = System.Convert.ToChar(last1);

              if ((last >= 'a' && last <= 'z'))
              {
                  int i = 2;
                  logonname = extLogonName + i.ToString();
              }

              if (last >= '2' && last <= '9')
              {

                 // char last2 = extLogonName[extLogonName.Length - 2];
                  string last3 = extLogonName.Substring(extLogonName.Length - 2, 1);
                  char last2 = System.Convert.ToChar(last3);
                  if (last2 >= '0' && last2 <= '9')
                  {
                      int number2 = (int)last2;

                      number2 = number2 + 1;
                      logonname = logonname + number2.ToString();
                  }

                int number = (int)last;
                 //Char number =System.Convert.ToInt32(last);

                  number = number + 1;
                  logonname = logonname + number.ToString();
              }
```

so it create 'moni.yewriwe2' then 'moni.yewriwe51' and i want 'moni.yewriwe3'.

Answer (score 0):

In the ASCII table, decimal 50 (hex 32) represents the character '2'.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Debugging can be a pain.  Glad to help.

Comment: Referring to ASCII could cause confusion. '2' is a UTF-16 code unit (`char`). UTF-16 is one of several encodings for the Unicode character set. UTF-16 encodes a codepoint in one or two code units. In the case of "2", only one is needed. `'2' == 50`. See [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) for a list of codepoints and [here](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) to see how UTF-16 works.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @TomBlodget.